# JQuery JSON data not displaying

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am having trouble displaying some jason from a page.

The data is there but I think it might have to do with this line:

```
document.write(fbResults.cats[0].title);
```

Here is the full html source:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.getJSON('http://mydomain.com/api/get_cats', function(fbResults) {
            document.write(fbResults.cats[0].title);
        });
    });
</script>

</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

And here is the data that it's reading:

```
{"cats":[

{"id":"1","title":"mytitle1","colour":"#EE297C"},
{"id":"2","title":"mytitle2","colour":"#EE412F"},
{"id":"3","title":"mytitle3","colour":"#F5821F"},
{"id":"4","title":"mytitle4","colour":"#00AEEF"},
{"id":"5","title":"mytitle5","colour":"#00B495"},
{"id":"6","title":"mytitle6","colour":"#006476"}

]}
```

It is not displaying anything on the page.

On firebug console I get this error:

The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the page must to be declared in the document or in the transfer protocol.

No traces of the json data there

What I'm I doing whong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't document.write after the page has loaded (which is certainly the case here).

If you want to write it to the page, you'll need to create HTML and append it.  Just replace the document.write:

```
$('body').append('<p>'+fbResults.cats[0].title+'</p>');
```

---

Update:

Your example makes a fully qualified URL call.  Is that server the exact same one that you're running the page from?  If it isn't the XHR will just eat the request (and sometime not tell you).  If you need to go cross domain, you'll need to use JSONp.  If you're attempting to run this locally while pulling data from the net, it'll break.

Comment: According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.write?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=document.write) you can, but I agree that it's better to append a new element, or update an existing one, rather than use document.write

Comment: Hmm.  You're right on both counts (although... anyone who uses document.write on a document that has already been closed is in for trouble).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 $.each(fbResults.cats,function(index,item){
    document.write(item.title);       
  });
```

Working sample : http://jsfiddle.net/zWhEE/8/

Comment: OK, your code works when I add the data to the actual page as you did but when I change the code and add "$.getJSON('http://mydomain.com/api/get_cats', function(fbResults) ... instead it's not reading it although the data is exactly the same. Could it be because I'm running the page on my pc desktop and not on any server?

Comment: Are you doing a cross domain call ?

Comment: Well, my html page is on my pc desktop and I'm trying to get the data from an online page...is this a problem?

Comment: you can not do that becuase of same origin policy http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

Comment: so I need to download the json data locally?

Comment: @Satch3000 - No, you need to run your page off of a server.  You can't really run JSON at all from a local file.

Comment: either you should server your JSON data from the same website you have this page where you access it or use jSONP to get the data from remote  pages ( the server page should send the response in jsonp format)

Comment: I don't totally understand. If this is the case why does it work when I connect to Facebook?

Answer (score 0):

its seems work for me please check this
http://jsfiddle.net/TxTCs/1/